# XML tags in Android- Is there a reference

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I'm doing an Android XML GUI layout:

```
<EditTextPreference
android:key="PREF_LT_500"
android:title="Step 1"
android:summary="aaaaa"
android:inputType="number" 
android:defaultValue="0"
android:dialogTitle="yyy" />
```

1)I want the inputType to be a decimal. I'm struggling to find the XML value that can provide this. inputType="number" only permits the digits, not the ".".  What must the inputType value be to force the input to be a decimal number?

2)In general, I find it time wasting and difficult to try and figure out the XML tags and permitted values. I'm wading through the Android references, and sometimes the tags are listed, but often not.  Is there a reference for the XML GUI schema?

3)I'm using Eclipse, and if I use the XML editor, it seems that some of the values are not resolving. It doesnt show the possible values for "inputType". Maybe my Eclipse is missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer to part 1 of my question. inputType="numberDecimal".
I would still like to know how to make it easier to figure out the Android XML Schema

Comment: In some occasions if you start typing a given attribute too fast, Eclipse doesn't give you autocomplete suggestions. Instead, try typing just `android:` and wait for a second or two while Eclipse loads the available attributes AND their respective options (e.g. "numberDecimal"). As for the documentation, the Android Developer documentation is pretty extensive. Particularly the attribute you are referring to can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType).

Comment: Thanks, I need to fix the setup of my IDE. I'm using the text editor instead of an XML editor for my XML, so  there are no suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to part 1 of my question.

```
inputType="numberDecimal".
```